# Is there a CSS workaround for one of the Firefox' bug with shrinking content?

Tags: firefox, css, flexbox

Here is a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/GCahV/ (compare it in Firefox and any other modern browser)

What I want to achieve:

1. There must be an inline block (or at least a block with `float`) with two parts: left and right.
2. These parts must be side-by-side and must be flexible, right part can be absent at all.
3. The parent block must have some `max-width` (in `%` or fixed in `px`).
4. When the left part is big enough, it must be overflowen, but the right part must always be shown.

Using `inline-block`, `float` and `overflow: hidden` I made it work well in the latest Chrome, Safari and Opera, but struck with the fact that Firefox have a bug: the left part shrinks when the right part is long.

The only CSS workaround I've found is to try position elements for Fx in flex-box model, but it's not perfect: I couldn't make the parent to have `max-width` (or `width` at all).

Here is my best try so far: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/GCahV/1/

---

So, the questions are:

1. Is there a way to make Firefox understand `max-width` for `.b-shrinker`?
2. Is there any other **CSS only** workaround for this Firefox' bug or completely different way to do what I want?

Comment: +1 for abbreviating Firefox as Fx rather than FF. Anyway, which versions of it does this affect?

Comment: I've tested from 3.0.19 till 6.0.1 — all of them have this bug.

Comment: +1, hopefully you ensured there is a bug filed on bugzilla?

Comment: There is a [similar bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396821) from the 2007 with nested floats and a few less similar. Still, no workarounds in bugzilla. Maybe, I'll file this bug a little bit later (after I'd create more minimal testcases).

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. I think it is an case that is not specified in the css specs. It was never specified in css 2 how floats should behave if you don't specify a width. I don't know if this has changed in css3 though. So different browsers handle these edge cases differently.

Comment: Well, not exactly: IE8+, Opera, and all Webkit browsers treat this case equally. And the expected behavior is logically the right one.

Comment: @kizu: Opera often goes against spec or follows unspec'd behavior to match other browsers. If it's not in the spec though, than we historically can't expect all browsers to define it a specific way. That's just how the browser wars go.

Comment: “Agains spec” and “unspec'd behavior” are different things. So, when everyone is renders the same and then one of browsers renders something differently (and the case is not in the spec) the most popular rendering goes to the specs. That's how the web-standards go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with playing with the flexbox a bit I found a somewhat nice solution: http://dabblet.com/gist/4701626

The only problem it have is that Fx loses the ellipsis for the left part, but it's a minor problem, 'cause everything else works fine.

So, here is a code that fixed it:

```
.b-wrapper_fixed .b-shrinker__in {
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-direction : reverse;
    }
.b-wrapper_fixed .b-shrinker__left {
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;   
    height: 1.2em;
    }
.b-wrapper_fixed .b-shrinker__right {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;   
    }
```

Except for making the block flexboxy, the left block need to have `white-space:normal` and `word-break: break-all`, so the long content in the left part won't make this part longer than the body. And to make the overflown content to be hidden, there is `height` set.

So, the only problem left is the missing ellipsis, so if someone would find a solution for this — I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

1. From what I read, Fx understands max-width from version 1.0 on.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width#Browser_compatibility. The ellipse works from Fx 7.0 on. So it is not implemented yet.
2. Give .b-shrinker `{ max-width: 100%; width: 100% }` and it will look good in Fx and WebKit and Opera. http://jsfiddle.net/GCahV/11/

Comment: 1. It understands `max-width` only while the block don't have `flex-box` behavior. When it's there — `max-width` magically stop working.
2. Read carefully: “There must be an inline block” — setting `width: 100%` would stretch block to the full width, but what I want: is to be it inline and shrinked as long as there a little content.

Comment: 1. That is true, maybe because the flexbox behaviour is still a working and the firefox flexbox behaviour is outdated. I wouldn't use the flexbox at all until it isn't working draft anymore. 2. I read that,but I don't think you can achieve it with the current fx version.

Comment: 1. For my case it just make the block to look better than it was when affected by the bug. 2. Well, right now I achieve this behavior using JS, but if someone would find a way to outsmart Fx, that'd be nice.